# Tiny MCE: How to allow people to indent

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to find out how to allow people to indent in Tiny MCE editor. Right now, whenever someone presses `tab` they just move into the next field. Is there any piece of code that will allow them to actually hit `tab` and have it create a tab for a new paragraph.

Comment: This article talks about this problem: http://www.pixelastic.com/blog/159:tabindexing-and-inserting-tabs-with-tinymce

Comment: @Tim I'm very confused. Every time I do a web search on this problem, I just find links with people with the opposite problem. When I hit tab, it jumps to the next field. It seems that whenever anyone else hits tab, it doesn't jump to the next field (your article as well).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can catch this event and `stopPropagation/return false` in case the user presses tab.

```
// Adds an observer to the onKeyUp event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, evt) {
          console.debug('Key up event: ' + evt.keyCode);
          if (evt.keyCode == 9){ // tab pressed
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, '\x09'); // inserts tab
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            return false;
          }
      });
   }
});
```

In case the user inserts a tab at the beginning or end of a paragraph it will get deleted by the browser (a workaround for this is to insert a special character of a predefined length that is not a tab).

Comment: Is there any way to stop the curser from jumping to the next field. Right now, it inserts the tab, but moved to the next field as well.

Comment: that was my failure (it is necessary to stop the bubbling of the event), i corrected it in my code above

Comment: This worked for me - mostly. I changed `'mceInsertRawHTML'` to `'mceInsertContent'` and `'\x09'` to `'&emsp;&emsp;'`. Also, `evt.preventDefault();` without `evt.stopPropagation(); return false;` is sufficient to suppress the default behaviour and still allows other scripts to handle this event.

Comment: It is also possible to indent using the indent, outdent button (but depending on ones use case this is not what is desired).

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined

Comment: this is code for tinymce 3.x instaed of ed.onKeyDown.add you will have to use ed.on('keydown' for tinymce 4.x

Answer (score 30):

For newer versions of Tiny MCE editor the following solution worked for me:

```
setup: function(ed) {
    ed.on('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 9) { // tab pressed
          if (event.shiftKey) {
            ed.execCommand('Outdent');
          }
          else {
            ed.execCommand('Indent');
          }

          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not the same as a tab character.

Answer (score 5):

The answers given here didn't quite match my requirements as I needs to indent text in the middle of a line. I was listing the names of office branches and wanted their phone numbers aligned together. With each office name being a different length I tried a combination of @Mac's answer and spaces but I couldn't get it accurate enough so I added a small space option using the shift key and space bar which allowed me to get everything lined up perfectly. The only downside is that the default entities for tinymce don't include `&hairsp;` so I have had to add the default entity list to my settings and add "8202,hairsp" at the end.

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.on('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 9) { // tab pressed
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&emsp;&emsp;'); // inserts tab
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 32) { // space bar
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&hairsp;'); // inserts small space
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Am struggling with this issue as well @richard.holmes . Your solution is the best so far. The best one would be for tabs to follow an invisible grid to have increments of x pixels. This so from 0 it would go to 25px for example and even if in the middle of a line it would go the next grid line with an increment of 25px based on the initial start position. For this I have not found any examples.

Answer (score 4):

Thariama's solution didn't quite work for me. I agree with Jon Hulka's fix. This seems to work fine on Firefox (mac+pc), Chrome (mac+pc) and Internet Exploder. It's not perfect, but I find it very usable and acceptable. Thanks Jon

So, to wrap op Jon's solution:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, evt) {
          if (evt.keyCode == 9){
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '&emsp;&emsp;');
            evt.preventDefault();
          }
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done via   nonbreaking plugin available in tinymce

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "nonbreaking",
  mewnubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "nonbreaking",
  nonbreaking_force_tab: true
});
```

details can be found on https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/nonbreaking/

Answer (score 1):

**you can easily added tab space using following code**

```
    ed.on('keydown',function(evt){
            if (evt.keyCode==9) {
                ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<span class="mce-nbsp">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</span>');
                tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(evt);
                return;
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For tinyMCE v5 the react version, this is what worked for me:

```
<Editor
  init={{
    setup: (ed) => {
      ed.on('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Tab') {
          if (event.shiftKey) {
            ed.execCommand('Outdent');
          } else {
            ed.execCommand('Indent');
          }
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For code snippet editing, if you want to avoid using `execCommand` and keep the cursor active after pressing the tab key :

```
    add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function($init){
        
        $init['setup'] = "function(ed) {

            ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, e) {
                
                //tab key
                
                if( e.keyCode == 9 ){
                                            
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    
                    if (e.shiftKey) {
                        
                        // TODO Outdent or use delete
                    }
                    else {
                        
                        // Indent
                        
                        ed.selection.setContent('\x09',{format:'raw'});
                    }
                }
            });
        }";
        
        return $init;
    });
```